# How to correctly organize headings for good Web accessibility?

Tags: html

So far I have 4 rules but I am not sure if this is necessary or not.
Rules for headers:

1. Must be only one H1 tag at page
2. The heading elements H1 to H6 should be used hierarchically correct.
3. Use aria-labelledby for div related to header (I am not sure if this is necessary?)
4. Use header tags only for headers, not for styling.

example {

```
<h1 id="hContinent">Continent</h1>
<div aria-labelledby="hContinent">
    About Continents …
</div>

<h2 id="hEurope">Europe</h2>
<div aria-labelledby="hEurope">
    About Europe …
</div>

<h3 id="hSpain">Spain</h3>
<div aria-labelledby="hSpain">
    About Spain …
</div>

<h3 id="hGerman">German</h3>
<div aria-labelledby="hGerman">
    About German …
</div>

<h2 id="hAsia">Asia</h2>
<div aria-labelledby="hAsia">
    About Asia …
</div>
```

}
Are this 4 rules correct or not?
Is there something else that need to be done with header to provide good Web accessibility?

Comment: So what if is opinion? I am asking for opinion. I will pick what is ok and what is not ok for me. Somene elese will do same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rules 1, 2, and 4 summarize the key technical principles of using heading elements. The most important thing to be added is that heading texts should be short, informative, and descriptive of the content that they are headings for. In particular, the headings should give a good idea of the content as a whole and the content of each part when read in isolation, as this is one important way of “consuming” them in accessibility software.

The `aria-labelledby` attribute is commonly not used for headings, and it is mainly intended to be used when an association with some labeling text and the labeled element is otherwise difficult to see. In a case like this, the association is programmatically determinable, since the old implicit principle (spelled out in HTML5) is that a heading element is a heading for a section that ends before the next heading of the same or higher level. Besides, there is not much evidence that accessibility software would make specific use of such an association; it lets users identify headers, have them presented in special ways, etc., and to continue reading from the content right after a heading, but the appearance of the next heading is a sufficient signal of end of section, as a rule.

Thus, rule 3 is not needed. If it is applied, it is not quite clear whether the heading should be moved inside the `div`, as it is the [MDN example on `aria-labelledby`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Accessibility/ARIA/ARIA_Techniques/Using_the_aria-labelledby_attribute). Here, as usual, ARIA markup examples are simple, used in situations where it is questionable whether it is needed. The reason, of course, is that a more realistic example where ARIA attributes really matter to accessibility are more difficult to compose and understand.

Answer (score 1):

To begin with many tags in HTML were developed not to assist formatting but to provide information on the structural hierarchy of a document. In order to facilitate accessibility as well as standards, it is best to use the tags for the intended purpose in the information hierarchy rather than for pure formatting purposes. In many cases, this will make your document easier to edit as well.

**Synopsis**
Use the `H1, H2,...H6` tags as indicators of section headings and subheadings within a document, not just as formatting elements. Screen readers in particular may just scan a page for appropriate `H1, H2 and H3` elements. [Good and bad header examples](http://accessibility.psu.edu/headingshtml#heading).

Many experts recommend reserving `H1` for the page title, `H2` for major headings and `H3` for major sub headings.

If you need to indent text for a quote it is generally preferable to use the `BLOCKQUOTE` tag rather than a `UL` unordered list tag. The UL tag should be reserved for true lists containing LI elements.

If you need to indent text stylistically (e.g. indent all paragraphs), it is better to use a CSS specification and add space to the left margin (e.g. `{margin-left: 15px}`) or left padding.

Use the `P` paragraph tag to separate paragraphs instead of multiple breaks (e.g. `BR BR` ). This encloses blocks of text within their own structural elements. Some screen readers are able to jump from `P to P` but not `BR to BR`.

Do not use the `FONT` tags to adjust formatting of heading tags. Experts recommend using cascading style sheets for specifying font color, font-size, font-face and backgrounds (versus the FONT tag). This allows a user with color vision or low vision to override a problematic stylesheet with one that they prefer.

In Word, using the `Heading 1`, `Heading 2` styles performs a similar function as `H1`, `H2` do and may be converted to approproate H tags in different conversion tools. You can edit Word Styles to change the appearance of these headers.

**Reference** - http://accessibility.psu.edu/headingshtml

In conclusion, I according to your question I can say you are correct in `1`, `2`, not sure about `3` and you are correct in `4` - you can don't need to use `H1` only if you want to make a bigger font, you can do it via styles..

Personally, I prefer to make it as much simple as I could so I use `H1 for titles`, `H2 for headers` and `P for content` and I've never used `aria-labelledby` in my projects.